# //= require_tree not including files in current tree in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use rails 3.2. In my application.js file I wrote:

```
//= require_tree .
```

Shouldn't it load all files in the app/assets/javascript directory (excluding subfolders)?

Well, it does not. What can be the problem?

Comment: My bad, I misread the question. Do you get any errors? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Could you please post your entire application.js as well as what your app/assets/javascript directory structure looks like?